# Spring Security + JPA - Use many business models (entities) for User authentication

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am using `Spring Boot` with `Spring Security` and `Spring Data JPA`. 
I have a `User` entity that I use for authentication.  I also have a Service extending `UserDetailsService` and have registered it in my SecurityConfiguration.

Now what I want, is to use two other entities for example `Employer` and `Employee` that will be my business models. Each entity has its own different properties (the Employer and Employee entities is just an example, could be something else). I want to use both entities for authentication, meaning a user can register as an Employee providing the besides the `User`'s properties (email, password ...) the `Employee`'s properties (gender, hire_date ...).

- Should I extend the `User` class the I am currently using? How would this work?
- Should I create the two entities and then relate them with a one-to-one relationship with the User entity?
- Is there another way?

I don't know what is the right approach. What are the best practices? An example will be highly appreciated.

Here is my User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    public String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String firstname;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String lastname;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String password;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;


    public User() {
    }

    public User(User user) {
        this.email = user.email;
        this.firstname = user.firstname;
        this.lastname = user.lastname;
        this.password = user.password;
        this.role = user.role;
    }


    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Since nobody has answered yet, I am thinking that maybe I explained it wrong. I just want to use 2 or more business models (entities) for user authentication. That's all.

Comment: All approaches should work. So, I think you should have your domain model as per your choice, depending on your business use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar dilemma in my system. We chose to use different Entity for only security model (username, password, authorities, etc.) and abstract `User` (with id and email - which is mandatory and unique), which was in 1:1 relationship to this `Authentication`. So we managed to extend the `User` and model specific representations in domain. Same way if you want to create another way to do authentication. You can do abstract `Authentication` and later `TokenAuthentication` (example for OAuth) or `BasicAuthentication` (with username and password).

One of the best approach I have seen was with aggregation of 3 Entities:

- abstract Authentication - extend to provide specific way to authenticate (token, login:pass)
- Principal - store authorities and other data needed for security (authorites,..)
- abstract User - extend for specific data for user in domain (email, forname, surname,...)

relationships: Authentication -(N:1)- Principal -(1:1)- User